# Vue3 - HTMLInputElement.target.value does not include decimal point?

Tags: vuejs3

I'm trying to create a numbered input with a max length.

However, when I try to type `1.2345`, anything after the decimal doesn't get stored. Upon further inspection, `target.value` never includes the decimal point despite being a string. Why is that?

```html
<script>
let props = defineProps({
  hint: String,
  min: Number,
  max: Number,
  maxLen: Number,

  modelValue: Number,
})
let emits = defineEmits({
  'update:modelValue': (it: number) => true
})

function onInput(event: Event) {
  let target = event.target as HTMLInputElement
  if (!target) return

  console.log(typeof target.value, target.value) // <<< prints string, 1
  target.value = target.value.slice(0, props.maxLen)

  // let value = +target.value
  // let oldValue = value
  // value = Math.min(value, props.max ?? value)
  // value = Math.max(value, props.min ?? value)

  // u.log(oldValue, value)
  // if (oldValue !== value) {
  //   u.log('update', value)
  //   target.value = '' + value
  //   emits('update:modelValue', value)
  // }
}
</script>
<template>
  <input class="form-control
        block
        w-full
        px-3
        py-1.5
        text-base
        font-normal
        text-gray-700
        bg-white disabled:bg-gray-100 
        bg-clip-padding
        border border-solid border-gray-300
        rounded
        transition
        ease-in-out
        m-0
        focus:text-gray-700 focus:bg-white focus:border-blue-600 focus:outline-none
        "
      type="number"
      @input="onInput"
      :placeholder="hint" />
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

> *target.value never includes the decimal point despite being a string. Why is that?*

When using `<input type="number"/>`, the input's `value` is converted from a string to a number, and then gets converted to a string again, at which point th decimal is removed. This is why when you enter `1.2` you get `21`  (you can also use `valueAsNumber` which skips making it into a string, but doesn't really solve the problem)

- type `1` => onInput `target.value` is `1`
- type `.` => onInput `target.value` is still `1` (not `1.`)
- onInput updates the value from `1.` to `1` and because of the change, the caret is now at the beginning
- type `2` => onInput `target.value` is `21`

That's the problem, as to your solution, it depends on your expected behaviour.

you could try something like this to validate whether the value needs to be updated instead of just updating it

```js
const max = 5;
const newVal = target.value.slice(0, max)
if(parseFloat(newVal)+"" !== newVal) {
    target.value = parseFloat(newVal)
}
else if(newVal !== target.value) {
    target.value = parseFloat(newVal)
}
```